# SpriteKit -- How to make a transparent font into a solid one

Tags: ios, fonts, transparent

So I am currently developing a game using SpriteKit

I have a font that is basically just edges, so the inside of the letters are all transparent, and I wanted to know how I could go about making that a solid font (preferably programmatically).